# How to do sort/merg using two threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to do Array sort/merg using two threads. But somehow it is not working (Still the array is not sorted)  probably due to some misunderstanding of threading or something else. Would appreciate to have your help. ps: I do have to use two threads as it is required for the assignment.

**Original Code**

```
public void sort(int[] data, int lo, int hi) 
{
    if (lo < hi) {
        // divide into two halves
        int mid = (lo + hi) / 2; 
        // sort the two half recursively
        sort(data, lo, mid);
        sort(data, mid+1, hi);
        //Combine the two halves
        merge(data, lo, hi, mid);
    }
}

private static void merge(int[] data, int lo, int hi, int m)
{
    .....
```

**This is what I do**

```
public class Sort 
{
    public void sort(int[] data, int lo, int hi) 
    {
        if (lo < hi) {
            int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
            Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    sort(data, lo, mid);
                }
            });
            Thread t2=new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    sort(data, mid+1, hi);
                }
            });
            t1.start();
            t2.start();

            try {
                t1.join();
                t2.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Combining two halves 
            merge(data, lo, hi, mid);
        }
    }

    private static void merge(int[] data, int lo, int hi, int m)
    {
                int[] temp = new int[hi - lo + 1]; 
    int i = lo; 
    int j = m+1;
    int k = 0; 
    while(k < temp.length) {
    if (i <= m) {
    if (j <= hi) {
    if (data[i] < data[j])
    temp[k++] = data[i++];
    else
    temp[k++] = data[j++];
    } else
    temp[k++] = data[i++];
    } else
    temp[k++] = data[j++];
    }
    for (k = lo; k<=hi; k++)
    data[k] = temp[k - lo];
   }
```

Comment: Without seeing how your `merge` method looks, it is hard to tell what is wrong. Also, how is it unsorted? Can you show some simple example input and corresponding output?

Comment: Just by creating and array in the main method then call sort method by passing the array and lower and higher limit. When I just just the original code it can be sorted but with multihtreading it is not working.

Comment: whats the result you got thus far? _"but with multihtreading it is not working"_ isn't helping us to understand your problem.

Comment: I ran your thread-based code, it gives a sorted output. probably you have specified incorrect limits

Comment: You should post the code of your "merge" method. But I don't understand why you would merge both, as long as you work on the first half and the second half of the same array. Also, I don't understand how your first code is working if you just call the sort method without any sorting (merge shouldn't sort anything I guess).

Comment: @Samuel Kok: if I use threading then the output is like this. 
506,8,90,450, 594, 624,766,829,939,962,989, 205...... However, with first code the output is given sorted. @ mangusta: I call like this: sort1.sort(testArray, 0, arraySize-1); in my case threading is not working. Probably it depends on where we run it. @ Asoub: Merg has the logic of sorting :).

Comment: Oh right this is a merge sort ! :) Could you provide the merge code to see what it does ? Normally there should be a temporary table passed through all of the merge calls ..

Comment: I added the merge code also.